# Using dyplr to group_by and then mutate time series data

Tags: r, datetime, grouping, dplyr

My data is available [here](https://figshare.com/s/ace5b44bc12394a7c46d). This is what my data looks like:

```
sq_id trialnumber trialdate trialtime 
22640  2          07/13/17   8:45   
22640  1          06/11/17  11:24
22641  1          06/12/17   9:37
22653  1          06/20/17  11:50 
22658  2          07/13/17   9:20 
22658  1          06/14/17  10:12
```

I am trying to calculate the time between `trialnumber`= 2 and `trialnumber`= 1 for `sq_id` with two `trialnumber`'s.

Since I had my date and times in separate columns I combined them like below:

```
#adding time between trials to data
trialdate<-as.POSIXct(OFT$trialdate,format="%m/%d/%y")
OFT$datetime=as.POSIXct(paste(trialdate, OFT$trialtime),format= '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M',usetz=FALSE)
```

I then tried to `group_by` `sq_id` and `trialnumber`, but cannot figure out how to get this to work.

```
data <- data %>%
        group_by(sq_id, trialnumber) %>%
        mutate(two=trialnumber %in% "2", one=trialnumber %in% "1") %>%
        mutate(timebtw=two$datetime-one$datetime)
```

Does anyone have a suggestion on how I can calculate the time between `trialnumber` = 2 and `trialnumber` = 1 for `sq_id` that have two `trialnumber` values (1 and 2), while adding NAs for `sq_id` with only one `trialnumber`?

Comment: I would probably filter all those with two trial numbers, spread the data to wide format and use `mutate()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a `tidyverse` solution. The key is that `dplyr` likes you to work with one observation per row. Here you are implicitly changing your understanding of the data from one observation being a trial, to one observation being an ID. We consequently `spread` the data so that each ID has its own row and then simply use `mutate` to get the difference between the two date-times. I also used `lubridate`'s `mdy_hms` parser out of habit, but your `as.POSIXct` is fine too. Note that the `NA` are generated automatically since `-` returns `NA` if one argument is `NA`.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'lubridate'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     date
tbl <- read_table2(
  "sq_id trialnumber trialdate trialtime
22640  2          07/13/17   8:45
22640  1          06/11/17  11:24
22641  1          06/12/17   9:37
22653  1          06/20/17  11:50
22658  2          07/13/17   9:20
22658  1          06/14/17  10:12"
)

tbl %>%
  mutate(date_time = mdy_hms(str_c(trialdate, trialtime))) %>%
  select(sq_id, trialnumber, date_time) %>%
  spread(trialnumber, date_time, sep = "_") %>%
  mutate(time_gap = trialnumber_2 - trialnumber_1) %>%
  select(sq_id, time_gap)
#> # A tibble: 4 x 2
#>   sq_id time_gap        
#>   <int> <time>          
#> 1 22640 31.8895833333333
#> 2 22641 <NA>            
#> 3 22653 <NA>            
#> 4 22658 28.9638888888889
```

Created on 2018-02-26 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: nice use of str_c

Comment: Thank you for explaining what goes on. That really helps improve my knowledge of the coding. As I am fiddling around with it myself, I noticed that the code doesn't work if I exclude the `select()` part of the code. Why is it necessary to indicate which columns to select? I ask because my original dataset has around 42 columns that I want to retain.

Comment: In this case, if you do not drop the original `trialdate` and `trialtime` the `spread` will place `date_time` on separate rows, because it can't compress two rows worth of `trialdate` and `trialtime` into one. If you want to retain the other columns, you need to decide how you want to do that. Are they constant within an `sq_id`? You could drop them and merge them back into your final table. See the `join` functions in `dplyr`, as well as the `select` helpers that make it easy to select 40+ variables.